# Windows API for drag'n'drop effect in pre 2000 era

Tags: winapi

Now all drag and drop operations between applications are done through DoDragDrop function. But I remember that the same was possible in Win95. It was possible to drag an icon from the desktop to Photoshop for example. How It was accomplished? According to msdn DoDragDrop was appeared only in Win2000.

Comment: Wasn't that done with [OLE Drag and Drop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96826a87.aspx)? Can't remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DoDragDrop` existed in Windows 95.  See this [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152092) that shows implemented drag and drop on Windows 95 with `DoDragDrop`

The minimum supported client/server listed online on MSDN don't mean that was when the API was first added. For example [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) lists Windows XP/Server 2003 as the minimum supported version and `CreateFile` has been around since the beginning of NT.

Comment: Right, "minimum supported" refers to technical support provided for development for that OS, not whether earlier OSes (now end-of-life) had the function.

Answer (score 1):

You may be thinking of [Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Data_Exchange).